# Ssms T-SQL Formatter

Tags: sql-server, sql

Подскажите плагин для форматирования Sql. Использую ssms 2014.

Попробовал установить: http://www.architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx

Безрезультатно, видимо нужно теперь установить плагин непосредственно в ssms, как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ниже список плагинов, пригодных не только для форматирования (*юзаю собственноручно*):

1. [ApexSQL Refactor](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_refactor.aspx) - лучший, на мой взгляд форматтер. Позволяет выполнять тонкую настройку стилей форматирования, сохранять её и импортировать/экспортировать.
2. [SSMSBOOST](http://www.ssmsboost.com/) - неплохой форматтер (*а в целом - вообще крутой и полезный инструмент*), однако после обновленния в ноябре была обновлена и политика лицензирования, что повлияло на функциональность бесплатной версии. Однако же на форматирование это не распространяется - это доступно по-прежнему.

---

Так же рекомендую ознакомиться с неплохой статьёй по теме расширения возможностей SSMS (*следует, однако, иметь в виду, что информация могла устареть*):

- [TOP (10) бесплатных плагинов для
  SSMS](https://habrahabr.ru/post/272895/)

Answer (score 1):

Если вы скачивали MSI-инсталлер, то после установки перезапускаете SSMS и в главном меню в Tools появятся 2 кнопки: "Format T-SQL Code" и "T-SQL Formatting Options".